# Trouble accessing WMS layer with leaflet in R

Tags: r, leaflet, wms

I am attempting to display an interactive map of past rainfall using leaflet in R. The best available data I was pointed to was located here: https://mapservices.weather.noaa.gov/raster/rest/services/obs/rfc_qpe/MapServer

The example layer I am trying to display is rainfall accumulation from the past 24-hours, indicated as layer 28. When trying to display with leaflet, the data does not seem to show, and no errors are given:

```r
library(leaflet)

url = "https://mapservices.weather.noaa.gov/raster/rest/services/obs/rfc_qpe/MapServer"

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addWMSTiles(url,
              layers="0",
              layerId = '28',
              options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png",
                                       transparent = TRUE,
                                       opacity=.7),
              group = "24-Hr Accumulation") %>%
  addLayersControl(overlayGroups = "24-Hr Accumulation")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Presumably, my issue is with the `layers = "0"` and `layerId = "28"` arguments.

Comment: WMS URL is: `https://mapservices.weather.noaa.gov/raster/services/obs/rfc_qpe/MapServer/WMSServer?`

Comment: There isn't a layer "0"

Comment: @nmtoken Okay. Layer 28 is the one I'm looking for, so I'm unsure which argument to give the value of `"28"`.

Comment: Layers is a WMS parameter so assume it would be `layers="28"`, `layerId ` is not a WMS parameter, but I don't know R, so not sure if it is translated to a valid WMS parameter when the request is generated.  A valid WMS GetMap request for layer 28 would be: https://mapservices.weather.noaa.gov:443/raster/services/obs/rfc_qpe/MapServer/WmsServer?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=13.70062800000000003,-178.0462459999999965,75.7345810000000057,-59.89828899999999834&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=470&HEIGHT=247&LAYERS=28&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE

Comment: @nmtoken Oh I see the issue, layer 28 provides some sort of boundary rather than a raster image that I was looking for. I should be using layer 26. Thank you for your help in finding this issue and fixing the URL!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me in R Studio:

```
library(leaflet)

url = "https://mapservices.weather.noaa.gov/raster/services/obs/rfc_qpe/MapServer/WMSServer?"
leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addWMSTiles(url,
    layers = "26,28", 
    options =  WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png",
        transparent = TRUE)
)
```

Gives:
[image: Two layers from WMS using Leaflet package in R]